# If a hacker manage to get my session token. then does that mean my account can be compromised?

Tags: security, web-applications

Web application manages and identifies it's client by cookies.. session maintenance is also based on cookies..if attacker managed to read my cookie(which obviously he can by packet sniffing) then can he log in to my account with that details?? how application server is prevent this from happening??

Comment: Is your connection done over SSL?

Comment: if the attacker watching over my ssl handshake..he can get key and other decryption settings.. am i wrong??@MateuszMrozewski

Comment: Have a look at the explanation in this thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server

Comment: ok what will happen in normal connection?? i mean non ssl connection??

Comment: In non SSL connection anyone on your network can sniff your traffic and see everything.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be impossible. The server does not identify the client with only the session value (cookie value). In addition to the session value, the server uses additional information such as the client ip to determine whether the session value (cookie value) is valid. If the attacker is involved in the first session using the Man-in-the-middle attack (MITM), the server knows the attacker's IP as the client IP and trusts the information provided by the attacker.
  The attack will succeed.

However, if you use SSL for the connection, the attack will fail.

As you can imagine, if an attack is successful with only a cookie value copy, any service that does not use https will be able to hack. Web technologies are designed so that they are not easily hacked.

check [this page](https://campus.barracuda.com/product/webapplicationfirewall/doc/42049419/cookie-replay-attack/)